# CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser SET Window.Name

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded

Using CefSharp browser in a WPF app we have a need to pass the Window Name (in a MVC web app it's just a matter of setting window.name = 'MyName' in jQuery on the view) but I'm not sure how to do this with an embedded browser within WPF before calling .Address

Any pointers would be appreciated :-)

Marked the accepted answer as it did answer the question, just discovered that it changed after the page was loaded. In the end passing to a function did the job, like this

```
Private Sub FrameLoaded(sender As Object, e As CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs)
    Try
        Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                                 Dim vBrowser As CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser = WebsiteLogin_Grid.FindName("WebsiteLogin_WebBrowser")
                                 vBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("loadFromManager(" & Current_ID & "); ")
                             End Sub)

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to bind the property to the WPF view as shown below.

```
<Window x:Class="CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp;assembly=CefSharp.Core"
        xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.Behaviours"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
        Title="{Binding Path=Title, ElementName=Browser, Converter={StaticResource TitleConverter}}"
        WindowState="Maximized">

</Window>
```

The converter code will look like :

```
public class TitleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "value ?? "No Title Specified";
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

refer [this documentation at github.](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/Converter/TitleConverter.cs)

If you want window.name or any other property, the solution is to register JS object:

```
webBrowser.RegisterJsObject("cefCallback", new JavascriptAdapter());
```

In JavascriptAdapter class you can create a method

```
public void SetWindowName(string name)
{
 //// your code
}
```

Then this method you can call from javascript of your HTML Page.

```
  window["cefCallback].setWindowName(window.name);
```

If you are not owning the HTML Page and you cannot change the page code, then you can use ExecuteScriptAsync to run a javascript method and get the result in C#.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there as method using (e.g. Title="WebsiteLogin_Page") from the xaml page when running in xaml.vb to change the Window Name dynamically? From the vb page I cannot seem to access 'ElementName' from Title

Comment: It is better to use this syntax (with MVVM Pattern) from the example, as it increases testability of your solution.   You can also do that in code behind file.  You can use TitleChanged event from the ChromiumWebBrowser. You will get new title in EventArgs (e.Title).  Set it to window text.

Comment: Just to be sure we are talking about the same thing - title is generally the text that appears in the browser tab when the page opens (e.g. 'Secure Login') - the window.name is passed silently and can be grabbed by jQuery. At the moment window.name is not being passed at all

Comment: It seems like Window.Name is added too late to post back to the server (html is dynamic based on this value. As an alternative I used FrameLoadEndEventArgs and passed the value to a function on the page that I will add to the question. I have marked your answer up. Thank you for taking the time :-)